# GCM Receiving Signal but not calling OnReceive() result=CANCELLED

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I keep getting this message in LogCat whenever I try to send a message from the demo GoogleAppEngine page that's built into Android Studio.

```
:GCM message com.objectivetruth.uoitlibrarybooking >0:1408853167972751%99d31532f9fd7ecd
:broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.objectivetruth.uoitlibrarybooking (has extras) }
:Unregister application com.objectivetruth.uoitlibrarybooking for user 0
:Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER (has extras) } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 ftg.a:1607 ftg.a:361
```

I'm about to rip my hair out after following [this guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints) from google twice from scratch to make sure I followed it perfectly and I keep getting the same errors on my device

What's crazy is that its growing, If i send another message, there will be a cascade of calls from, what I assume is, all the previous messages that haven't been dealt with as yet. I tried a local GAE instance then I uploaded it to the cloud and still same issue. The registration works fine AFAIK. 
I have a toast that tells me the resulting registration code which I assume means its success.
Also, the local server shows me every time a new registration occurs so I think that's fine as well

Here's my app Manifest's relevant parts which I've quadruple checked:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<permission
    android:name="com.objectivetruth.uoitlibrarybooking.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.objectivetruth.uoitlibrarybooking.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<receiver
    android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.objectivetruth.uoitlibrarybooking" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
```

and the GcmBroadcastReceiver

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Timber.i("Please please call me!");
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
```

Here's the GcmIntentService

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (extras != null && !extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            // Since we're not using two way messaging, this is all we really to check for
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                Timber.i(extras.toString());

                showToast(extras.getString("message"));
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    protected void showToast(final String message) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The AsyncGcmRegistration is copy/pasted from the guide

Really not sure what else might be wrong..

Answer (score 3):

OMG, if anyone stumbles upon this in the future and is tearing their hair out like I was, the reason you get result=canceled is because there's a legitamate issue with where the intent is going.

DO NOT IGNORE IT.

In my case I had the receive declarations outside my  tags so it was not recognizing the pkg correctly.

Do not ignore the manifest, if you have issues with receiving very high chance its because of it.